# Whats wrong with this vb.net code

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Ok so im trying to login to my MYSQL database and go to database 'vb' table 'login' and check weather the username and password they enter was correct or not.but i dont know how to do this in vb.

```
   Myconnection = "Host=LocalHost; user=root;password=tro63jans; username =" & username &
       "; password =" & password
```

Comment: Could you show a bit more of the login code?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Connection String:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Using a port number:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

uid and username...i think you have some kind of duplicates in your string, do not use both